# Parallax JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, parallax

I have this self made parallax site that I made with little help of Untame sample (http://untame.net/2013/04/how-to-integrate-simple-parallax-with-twitter-bootstrap/)..

Somehow this line gets error in dreamweaver:

```
var yPos = -(($window.scrollTop() – $scroll.offset().top) / $scroll.data('speed'));
```

Can someone tell me whats's wrong with it?

Comment: Do you have a link to the actual link of the page? Or could you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate the error? Otherwise it's difficult for us, for example $window could be undefined

Comment: ... and what is contents of the error?

Comment: Hi, I use this script on --> testi4.aada.fi to create parallax effext. I'm not familiar with jsfiddle..